# How can I extract all changed files of a changeset in Mercurial?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, subversive, changeset

Until recently we have been using SVN for all projects of our web studio, and there is a very convenient feature present in several clients like Subversive and TortoiseSVN that can extract all files that have been changed in a certain revision.

Is there a way to do it in Mercurial? I don't care if it's done via a GUI or a command line, it's just very convenient to have a set of files that have been changed in a certain changeset.

P.S. I must have put it wrong the first time. I need more than just a list of files, it would be great to have all the files exported to some other folder.

Comment: Do you mean the file name or content or diff of the files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on Jerome's answer this will get you the **copies of the files** that changed in revision 4:

```
hg archive --type files --rev 4 -I $(hg log -r 4 --template {files} | sed 's/ / -I /g') ~/changedfiles
```

That puts all the files that changed into revision four into a newly created directory named changedfiles in your homedir.

If you change it to:

```
hg archive --type zip --rev 4 -I $(hg log -r 4 --template {files} | sed 's/ / -I /g') ~/changedfiles.zip
```

then they show up in a zip archive.

It's worth noting that that only works if you have no spaces in filenames.  If you made that blunder then we'll need to use `hg status --print0 -r revision -r parent-of-revision` instead, but hopefully that's not necessary.

Note also that the revision number, '4' in our example, shows up twice.  The whole thing could very easily be wrapped in a shell script, and that would be parameterized so you don't have to remember to change it in both places.

Answer (score 7):

This gives you the list of modified files in revision 4:

```
hg log -r 4 --template {files}
```

**Update:** If you'd like to have one file per line, you may use [the style described in Hg book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html#id417978).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your ned, there are two command:

1. To get the changes associated with a particular revision, you can use `hg export`:

   ```
   hg export -r 23
   ```

This will generate a diff of all the changes (actually a formatted patch, ready to be applied)

2. To get the name all the files that were affected, you can use `hg log`:

   ```
   hg log -r 23 -v
   ```

This will print the meta-info for the revision, along with the names of the files that were affected.

Comment: you could also of course hg diff -r rev -r rev-1 which would be the same as the diff part of export

Comment: @jk, `hg export` is better than `hg diff`, as it eliminates the step of finding the parent changeset, which isn't always decremental (e.g. the numberings get messed up with merges and such).

Comment: @notnoop, you can use `hg diff -c` for that :)

Answer (score 0):

This command outputs names of all changed files in a specified revision:

```
hg export revision_num | grep ^diff | cut -f 6 -d ' '
```

Comment: That's almost what I need! I only need to somehow pipe the result to cp and copy all files to some separate folder. Thanks!